# Vaadin: button's layout is not displayed or not in the bottom

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I have Vaadin Vertical Layout which contains a horizontal layout with description, a panel with a table and horizontal layout with buttons. There is a problem with different displays:

1) On small monitors, button's layout is not visible.

```
public class ApprovalView extends VerticalLayout implements ClickListener
{      
      public ApprovalView()
      {
         setSizeFull();
         setSpacing(true);
         setMargin(true);
         initialize();
         addComponent(topLayout);
         addComponent(tablePanel);
         addComponent(bottomLayout);
      }
...
}
```

2) On large monitors, button's layout is not on the bottom. They sticks to the tablePanel that causes an ugly empty area on the bottom.

```
public class ApprovalView extends VerticalLayout implements ClickListener
{      
      public ApprovalView()
      {
         //setSizeFull();
         setSpacing(true);
         setMargin(true);
         initialize();
         addComponent(topLayout);
         addComponent(tablePanel);
         addComponent(bottomLayout);
      }
...
}
```

I tried to create a panel with another vertical layout with same content to make it scrollable but it only messed everything up. And scroll stopped until the buttons were shown.
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You have to the component heights in the VerticalLayout, otherwise it will just use 1/3 of the space for each "row". There is also a componentexpandratio which can be set. Look here for more infos: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html

Comment: try: setExpandRatio(tablePanel, 1);